# How can I find the messaging sounds that are used in Google's Messenger (sms) app?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, vanilla-android

I am trying to find the "message sent" "blip" sound specifically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AOSP: The AOSP Messages source code is [here](https://github.com/slvn/android-aosp-mms), but the source code **does not** have a "sent sound" (nor any sound) because those sounds are in your *system sounds*. You can find them at `/system/media/` from a file manager like [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en).

New [Google Messenger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging): The sounds can be found by decompressing the [.apk](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/messenger-google-inc/messenger-1-0-130-1616457-08-apk/). They are in `/com.google.android.apps.messaging/res/raw/`. All independent sounds are there!

Answer (score 1):

All system sounds can be found inside the `/system/media` folder.

Different to the `/data` partition the `/system` partition can be read with normal user permissions so you can easily copy those sounds; you don't need any source code (whyever would you need code for that?).

If you'd like to get an application specific sound then open the apk as a `.zip`-file and look out for the `assets` and `res/raw` folders.

Comment: Thanks, i looked there, but couldn't find the send sound. I was asking for source code because I figured it might be bundled with the app itself

Comment: then you may look inside the application package of the messenger (I predict "SMS/MMS") itself which you can find inside `/system/app`. Just open the apk as a zip-file. Inside this file the `assets` folder or the `res/raw`folder are the ones you may want to look for.

Comment: Cool didnt know about this location. It seems to contain every possible app but the messenger / sms app. Any other location ?

Comment: If you specifically search for the AOSP messenger app you may search for Mms inside `/system/app-priv`. I searched it already but there are no sounds inside because it uses the system sounds.